# exponential and limit question

Tags: calculus

How to prove $(1+\frac{x}{n})^n=e^x(1-\frac{x^2}{2n})+o(1/n^2)$?

$(1+\frac{x}{n})^n=e^{nlog(1+\frac{x}{n})}=e^{1-x-x^2/n-x^3/n^2+o(1/n^2)}$ but afetr?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

That's not actually the right expansion for $\log$. It should be
$$\log(1+y) = y - y^2/2 + y^3/3 + O(y^4)$$
which would in turn give you
$$(1+x/n)^n = \exp(n(x/n - (x/n)^2/2 + (x/n)^3/3 + O((x/n)^4))$$
$$ = e^x(\exp(-x^2/(2n)+O((x/n)^2).$$
I'll leave my calculations at this, as I don't want to give away the answer too much! If you can't complete it from here, give me a shout and I'll happily advise you further!

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\log (1 + \xi) = \xi - \xi^{2}/2! + o(\xi^{2})$ as $\xi \to 0$; hence, in fact we have
$$
\bigg( 1 + \frac{x}{n} \bigg)^{n} = \exp \bigg[ n \log \bigg( 1 + \frac{x}{n} \bigg) \bigg] = \exp \bigg[ n\bigg( \frac{x}{n} - \frac{x^{2}}{2n^{2}} + x^{2}o\bigg( \frac{1}{n^{2}} \bigg) \bigg] = \exp \bigg[ x - \frac{x^{2}}{2n} + o\bigg( \frac{1}{n^{2}} \bigg) \bigg]
$$
as $n \to \infty$.